# Cryptocurrencies based on RSA instead of ECDSA

Tags: public-key, cryptography, ecdsa

Bitcoin is based on ECDSA. Does anyone know of cryptocurrencies based on RSA for authentication?

Comment: Why? An RSA public key + signature for the same security level as 256-bit ECDSA would be almost 10 times as large, and slower to verify.